# Checking if an ISBN Book Number is valid Python

Tags: python

So I have been trying to convert this 'validator' from Pseudocode to Python, but I'm not too sure if my values are being put into a list. After I enter the first value, an error appears saying: `'int' object is not callable`. But then if I get rid of `isbn = mylist()`, it says that `name 'isbn' is not defined`. Can someone point me out where my mistake is?

I'm pretty sure I'm not setting up my list correctly.

Here is the PSEUDOCODE I'm following:

[image]

And my code:

```
def checkDigit():
    calculateDigit = 0
    count = 1
    calculateDigit = 10 - calculateDigit
    for count in range (1,14):
        mylist = int(input("Please enter the next digit of the ISBN: "))
 #      isbn = mylist()
    while (count <= 13):
        calculateDigit = calculateDigit + isbn[count]
        count = count + 1
        calculateDigit = calculateDigit + (isbn[count] * 3)
        count = count + 1
    while (calculateDigit >= 10):
        calculateDigit = calculateDigit - 10
    if (calculateDigit == 10):
        calculateDigit = 0
    if (calculateDigit == isbn[13]):
        print ("Valid ISBN")
    else:
        print ("Invalid ISBN")



checkDigit()
```

Comment: `mylist`is actually an integer which changes each iteration. If you want `mylist`to contain a list of all ISBN numbers, define `mylist` outside the for loop and append to it inside the foor loop. Also, I believe `input()` automatically converts to an `int` although I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre getting that error because you assign an int to mylist, and then call it. This is equivalent to something like

```
>>>5() # 'int' object is not callable error
```

try setting up your isbn like so for a string

```
isbn = ""
    for count in range (1,14):
    mylist = int(input("Please enter the next digit of the ISBN: "))
    isbn += mylist
```

or like this for a list of numbers

```
isbn = []
    for count in range (1,14):
    mylist = int(input("Please enter the next digit of the ISBN: "))
    isbn.append(mylist)
```

Comment: Okay I think that works. For some reason, it now throws an error saying list index out of range.

Comment: @Filip your pseudo code says you should loop up to (excluding, **<**) **13**, your code loops to (including, **<=**) **13**. Look at your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

mylist is an integer, you can't perform a mylist() operation

I think what you intend to do is `isbn.append(mylist)` so when the loop ends you have all the items stored in isbn